# determine the total number of the user's input

Tags: command-line, bash

```
echo -n "##### WHICH YEAR OR YEARS? #######"
read year
```

How I can check the total number of the user's input (year)? For example user's input as follows; 2013 2014 2015. Then, total number of the input is 3. There is always one space between the inputs. Which code gives the total number of the year inputs?

Comment: If you're taking user input, saying "there is always one space between the inputs" cannot possibly be true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Save the inputs in an array by using `-a` option of `read` and then count the number of elements of the array:

```
$ read -a year
2015 2016 2010

$ echo "${#year[@]}"
3


$ read -a year
2010 2019

$ echo "${#year[@]}"
2
```

---

Or use `wc -w`, no need for array:

```
$ read year
2013 2015 2017

$ wc -w <<<"$year"
3
```

---

Or you can set the positional parameters using `set` and then have a count:

```
$ read year
2015 2016 2017 2018

$ set -- $year

$ echo "$#"
4
```

---

To save it in a variable:

```
var="${#year[@]}"  ## For array

var="$(wc -w <<<"$year")"  ## For "wc -w"

var="$#"  ## For "set"
```

Comment: I also need to assign the answer to variable like, number= wc -w <<<"$year" but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: @deepblue_86 check my edits..